# Object not persistent on DontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Player in Scene1 that i want to persist to Scene2. Scene2 is correctly loaded but the Player does not apear.

```
    // PLAYER CLASS
    void Awake () {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }


// SCENE 1 MANAGER
  void Start () {

        Debug.Log(startString);

        Invoke("GoForth", 3f);


    }

    void  GoForth()
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
    }
```

Comment: What does your hierarchy in scene 1 look like?

Comment: http://imgur.com/g6vwacw

Comment: I can't access that link could you post the image in your question it would be easier.

Comment: Now i fixed it. Try to access it again.

Comment: It's not that, I can't currently access that website. Anyway what i wanted to verify was if your Player gameobject was the child of another object.

Comment: It is. And i just realised it cant be right? DontDestroyOnLoad needs to be called on an object that is at the root?

Comment: Yup exactly, if it's the child of an object it will get destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DontDestroyOnLoad` will only work on root level gameobject, if your gameobject is the child of another object it will be destroyed even if you call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on it.